# Bare metal setup for Spring DI

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Say I just want to have a simple Java executable (executable JAR) use Spring XML for dependency injection. I don't want *any* other Spring JARs or functionality (i.e. Spring MVC, Spring Batch, etc.). I simply want to use Spring for dependency injection and nothing more.

What are the bare bones minimal JARs I need on the classpath, and implementation I need to set up in my main `Driver` class (see below) to read a `myapp-config.xml` off the runtime classpath and inject the "roots" of my dependency tree?

```
public class Driver {
    private Widget widget;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        driver.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        // By this point, the widget instance should have been injected by Spring.
        widget.doSomething();
    }

    // Getter & setter for widget.
}
```

Comment: You need `spring-context` and all of its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis (+1) - and what annotations or subclasses do I need to use/implement? Could I just make `Driver` `ApplicationContextAware` if I have 1-and-only-1 Spring XML file on the classpath, or do I need to load a classpath app context (and if so, how)? Thanks again!